# using sed to alter a phrase with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Im a newbie to linux and trying to learn. I have a text file with dates which get produced daily but the dates are all fixed so I would like to alter specific dates in the text file by running a bash script.

I thought using sed with the syntax:

```
sed -i 's/01 January 1970/27 October 2017/'
```

However it doesn't seem to work?

this is the source file line:

```
#01 January 1970:-JOB1011,Complete&Successful
```

This is what i'd like it to look like once its been transformed:

```
#27 October 2017:-JOB1011,Successful
```

Any advice please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your command works for me.

Comment: Why should it remove `Complete&`? Was that a copying error?

Comment: Works for me too, with the important addition of the filename at the end of the command.  Perhaps that's related to your problem?

Comment: I tried it to change just the date and it works! but when I include the status which has an ampersand thats where i think I'm making a mistake.

Comment: If you want a literal `&`, you'll need to escape it.  `\&`

Comment: ah, thats done it! Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your datafile is 'x', I expect

```
sed -i 's/01 January 1970/27 October 2017/' x
```

to work:

```
$ cat x
#27 October 2017:-JOB1011,Complete&Successful
```

If that's not what you see, what versions of linux and sed are you using?

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
...
$ uname -srv
Linux 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 13:24:18 EDT 2017
```

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Linux 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017

The syntax is working for the date transformation, however if i change the status and if the status goes from Successful to Complete&Successful i get this:

#27 October 2017 Complete01 January 1970Successful:-JOB1011,Complete&Successful

Is the '&' introducing this and how can I rectify it?

Comment: As @zzxyz noted above, the & has a special meaning and needs to be escaped with \&. It is often used to put a long running process into the background so that you get your prompt back. It's also part of some output redirection operations (search for "bash output redirection")